# Replacing Delegates with Blocks

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I have recently started learning Objective C and came across Blocks/Closures. They look much like Annonymous inner classes in Java to me. I have read somewhere that *Blocks can be used to replace Delegates*. This confuses me as in case of Delegates you signal a method when a specific task completes, how can delegates be replaced by Blocks?

For Example in Java, Delegates are like:

```
button.addClickListener(new ButtonClickEvent(){

    void foo(){
       // some code
    }
});
```

In this case ButtonCLickEvent is a Protocol or in Java terms an Interface. **How can this be represented in terms of Blocks in Objective C?**

Comment: you can call back a block for instance after e.g. a procedure finished, if you like it, you can call those _completion blocks_, but in general: the caller / owner defines a block, pushed toward to the other class, which class invokes it at certain stage of the execution. sometimes those are more powerful solutions than calling back a method (i.e. much faster).

Comment: That Java is already very much like an Objective-C block. Maybe you should instead take a look at how delegates in Objective-C are implemented to see the difference. An Objective-C delegate is really just a callback. You are reading the term "delegate" in objective-C and then thinking its the same as Java delegate, that is why you are getting confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking if an object conforming to a specific delegate protocol that has been set as a `delegate` in some other object, can be replaced with a block after some *simple* fiddling, i'd say the answer is negative.

`Blocks` are just some sort of enhanced function pointers that can be used as callbacks. There is no reciprocal concept in Java, not even java8's *Function Objects*, because they are actual `Object` with a single method (i'm sure you are familiar with the concept of functional interfaces).

But this doesn't mean that `blocks` cannot be used as callbacks to respond to events, but you'll need some sort of adapter that will forward the usual Delegate method specified by a specific delegate protocol to the callback block that you have configured.

An extremely nice example of building something like this is represented by the library [ReactiveCocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa), using it you will be able to do something like this:

```
self.button.rac_command = [[RACCommand alloc] initWithSignalBlock:^(id _) {
    NSLog(@"button was pressed!");
    return [RACSignal empty];
}];
```

I'm not explaining here how it works (`RACSignal` is an abstraction that represent a stream of events), but i guess you can easily get the gist of what it does, really compact.

Update:

For more info on how blocks are implemented in the Foundation SDK, see [this post](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/10/how-blocks-are-implemented-and.html). Also check out this post from Mike Ash with [sample usage scenarios](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2008-12-26.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think best to use the Library.

For example, [SHUIKitBlocks](https://github.com/seivan/SHUIKitBlocks).

If you need block for button, check [SHControlBlocks](https://github.com/seivan/SHControlBlocks).